# Clean URLs (possibly with slug)

Tags: node.js, express

I am using mongodb to store data. And the default _id is long and not-clean. So now my routes are like: example.com/job/sdg3463retgeragsehxcwe35435ert5

Works fine.

But is there any way to auto increment Numbers and save a custom ID (with a field name like, serial_number)?

I implemented it this way: Created another collection to store the last saved serial number. Then while saving a new data, increment it. This works fine, but is there any better way?

Also, how to save urls with slug instead of ids? Do I need a separate collection to store the slug and its relevant id?

What if I use raw mongodb _id? Is it going to hurt the SEO drastically? Or any other issues?

This works fine, but just wondering how the pros do it.

Answer (score 3):

If you are willing to have alphanumeric ids the shortid module works pretty well. https://github.com/dylang/shortid

If you want actual slugs and are using mongoose you could try the mongoose-uniqueslus module. https://github.com/punkave/mongoose-uniqueslugs.git

Answer (score 1):

1. You should redirect all traffic to index.php using .htaccess
2. On index.php you have to select what to do with the url ending, which is storeg in the `$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]` variable
3. Depending on its value, you can show whatever you want :)

note: absolute links such as http://domain.com/index.php will continue to work unless you make some more changes in .htaccess.